# Deploy same war in two different paths (Tomcat)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I've been searching around how to do this, but the solutions I've found didn't solve my problem...

I have a Tomcat server and in it **/webapps** folder. I copy my **myApp.war**, restart the tomcat and access the app as:

```
domain.com/myApp
```

What I want is to have the same *.war* deployed in two different root paths where the second would be:

```
domain.com/beta/myApp
```

It is important that the root URL of the second app is **/beta/** and the first one **/**

I tried creating conf/Catalina/localhost/**beta.xml**:

```
<Context path="/beta” docBase=”/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/beta">
```

and then manually copying the content of the */opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/webapps/myApp* (that was automatically extracted by tomcat when first called) into */opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/beta*

I am sorry if this is a duplication of another question,but I simply couldn't make it work..

Comment: Would deploying your apps as domain.com/myApp and domain.com/myAppBetta work for you?

Comment: Olaf, I am afraid not :(